# Unsubscribe DataGridView from DoubleClick

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, event-handling

I am working with a WinForms `DataGridView` control. I have put this control in a base form and subscribed it to the `DoubleClick` event. But on the inherited form I want to unsubscribe it from the parent event, and subscribe it to a new event. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `protected` value to `DataGridView1.Modifiers` property and change the modifier of `DoubleClick` handler of `DataGridView1_DoubleClick` as protected.

Base form,

```
protected void DataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

In inherited from's load handler,

```
//To unregister handler
DataGridView1.DoubleClick-=new EventHandler(DataGridView1_DoubleClick); 
//Register new handler
DataGridView1.DoubleClick+=new EventHandler(NewDataGridView1_DoubleClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to mark the subscribed method `virtual` and have inherited forms `override` it.